# libkrb5.so.3 Missing

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-wheezy, shared-libraries

Suddenly after working fine my Raspbian (Wheezy) libkrb5.so.3 or its directory went missing. I suspect it was after a scheduled backup which is usually after update/upgrade and pi-update. I cannot use rpi-update anymore and probably among other things Samba daemon won't load. How can I reinstall this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `apt-cache search libkrb5`
2. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libkrb5-3`